# Pydantic Validation error: Input should be a valid dictionary or instance

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

I am trying to validate the latitude and longitude:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Location(BaseModel):
    longitude: float = Field(None, ge=-180, le=180)
    latitude: float = Field(None, ge=-90, le=90)


Location(longitude=1.0, latitude=1.0)
```

When I run this locally I get the following error:

```
Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of Location [type=model_type, input_value=ArgsKwargs((), {'longitud...: 1.0, 'latitude': 1.0}), input_type=ArgsKwargs]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/model_type
```

I have already tried to follow the [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.4/errors/validation_errors/#model_type) documentation which is given by the error but unfortunately is not clear and does not really give any information in regards of what to change and what to do differently.

I also tried to create a Python dictionary to see if the error could be solved but it still gave the same error.

Honestly, I have no idea of what to do next and how to solve this problem as I have tested it in several files (including in the same file to ensure it had nothing to do with any imports).

Any ideas of why the error occurs?

**Update**

Without the `(BaseModel)` when running the an instance of the dataclass in the same file it works. Now, I am creating different unit tests to test if the `validators` work correctly. Please check the following code snippet:

When creating a unit test and running a such test:

```py
 def test_when_location_is_not_in_range_then_print_exception(self):
        invalid_location = Location(latitude=200.0, longitude=300.0)

        with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as context:
            location = Location(latitude=invalid_location.latitude, longitude=invalid_location.longitude)

        self.assertEqual(
            str(context.exception), "Location is out of range", "Expected exception message: 'Location is out of range'"
        )
```

Before running the test, a warning appears: `Unexpected Argument`

After running the test, a new error appears:

```
longitude
  Input should be less than or equal to 180 [type=less_than_equal, input_value=300.0, input_type=float]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/less_than_equal
latitude

  Input should be less than or equal to 90 [type=less_than_equal, input_value=200.0, input_type=float]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/less_than_equal
```

The error encountered before does not appear anymore.

Comment: Can you show also your `import` statements? Tried running the code and it works for me.

Comment: It works for me as well.

Comment: These are the import statements being used
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're using `dataclass` from `pydantic.dataclasses`.

In that case, don't inherit from `BaseModel`

```py
from pydantic import Field
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Location:
    longitude: float = Field(None, ge=-180, le=180)
    latitude: float = Field(None, ge=-90, le=90)


Location(longitude=1.0, latitude=1.0)
```

Read more at https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/dataclasses/

---

Regarding the update to your question - the validation errors come from

```py
    invalid_location = Location(latitude=200.0, longitude=300.0)
```

You've limited the valid range of values for the `latitude` and `longitude` attributes, hence the errors when values provided do not adhere to those requirements.

Comment: This works when im doing the test in the same file. Whenever I try to construct the dataclass in a different file such as a testing file i get the following error: 

    `def setUp(self) -> None:
        address = Address(
            original_address="test",
            accuracy=Accuracy.ROOFTOP,
            location=Location(longitude=1.0, latitude=1.0),)`

`Unexpected Argument`

Comment: Even when I run a simple unit test I come back to the same error, This being the one from the main question. `Input should be a dictionary or an instance of Location [type=dataclass_type, input_value=Location(longitude=1.0, latitude=1.0), input_type=Location]`

Comment: Since the error you've mentioned regards a different model (`Address`), then perhaps you should change its definition as well.

Comment: Even when I change the definition of `Address` same issue appears. I just changed the `def setUp()` to create a `Location` object and still the `Unexpected Argument` Appears

Comment: Please include a Minimal Reproducible Example in the main question.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, you can see the updates in the main question. Thanks in advance