# Pydantic: Validation error when having a dataclass inside another dataclass

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

I am trying to solve an issue which is the following:

I have a dataclass within another dataclass:

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Location:
    longitude: float  
    latitude: float
```

Location is also added into the following dataclass:

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Address:
    original_address: str
    accuracy: Accuracy
    **location: Location**
```

When creating an instance of the object address on another class (in this case I am doing it on a test case file) a warning appears: `Unexpected Argument`

This is how the setup looks:

```py
 address = Address(
            original_address="text", 
            accuracy=Accuracy.ROOFTOP, 
            location=Location(latitude=90.0, longitude=180.0)
 )
```

When running the following test:

```py
    def test_when_location_is_not_in_range_then_print_exception(self):
        invalid_location = Location(latitude=200.0, longitude=300.0)

        with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as context:
            address = Address(
                original_address="test",
                accuracy=Accuracy.ROOFTOP,
                location=invalid_location,
            )

        self.assertEqual(
            str(context.exception), "Location is out of range", "Expected exception message: 'Location is out of range'"
        )
```

I encounter the following error:

```py
Input should be a dictionary or an instance of Location [type=dataclass_type, input_value=Location(longitude=180.0, latitude=90.0), input_type=Location]
```

I have done several tests around this and I still do not know how to solve it. One of the tests was done by doing the instance of the object in the same file and if it was done there everything seems to work. It is only when I do the instance on a different file that the error stated on top appears.

If by  any chance you want to see the investigation done before, please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77438553/pydantic-validation-error-input-should-be-a-valid-dictionary-or-instance)